# MongoDB: Apply Bson Update Query to Document Object

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

This might be a slightly unconventional scenario, but let me explain my situation. I have multiple clients that communicate with a central server. These clients send Bson queries to the server, which then processes and updates a specific document in MongoDB using MongoCollection#updateOne.

After the server updates the document, it sends the Bson query to all clients that have the related data active. This helps in keeping the active user data updated across all clients.

However, I've hit a roadblock in the following area:
The clients store relevant data in their memory. The objects that are stored are sent from the central server. My goal is to apply the same Bson query update to the Document objects stored on the clients, mimicking the behavior of MongoCollection#updateOne. It's important to note that the clients don't have any direct access to the database; they only work with the data provided by the central server.

In essence, I'm seeking a method to apply a Bson query update to a Document object without utilizing a MongoCollection. Is there a way to utilize MongoDB's functionality to achieve this, without requiring a custom implementation? Alternatively, are there any libraries or frameworks capable of efficiently handling this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to used MongoDB change streams feature .It essentially creates a cursor that remains open and continuously listens for changes to connected clients.
On server side MongoDB's official driver (e.g., MongoDB Node.js driver) to initialize a Change Stream and specify the collection you want to watch.
When any document in the watched collection is updated according to the specified criteria, the Change Stream is triggered. The server will receive a notification for that change event.
establish a real-time communication channel between the server and the clients using web-sockets.
When the Change Stream is triggered on the server, the server sends the updated data or the BSON query to the connected clients through the real-time communication channel. This can be done in JSON format or any other format suitable for your application.

this can be the flow:

1. Client A, B, and C are connected to the server through WebSockets
   (or other real-time communication).
2. The server sets up a Change Stream to watch a specific MongoDB
   collection.
3. Client A updates a document in the collection through the server
   using a Bson query.

4.The Change Stream on the server detects the change and sends a
notification to all connected clients (A, B, C).

5.Clients A, B, and C receive the update notification from the server
through Web-Sockets.

6.Each client (A, B, C) applies the BSON query locally to their
relevant Document object(s) stored in memory.

7.Now, all clients (A, B, C) have the updated data locally in their
memory, and they stay in sync with the changes made to the MongoDB
collection.

This approach ensures that all clients are updated with the latest data, and the central server remains responsible for handling all interactions with the MongoDB database.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I'm aiming to do!

Although I'm unsure on how to approach step 6. Usually the BSON query is applied via Mongo's Driver functions, but since I'm not applying query through a MongoCollection, how do I actually apply that query to the Document object?